# Unable to register PostalCode, Tiltle, locality and DOB in User Profile of WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am newbie to the WSO2 IS. I would like to configure PostalCode, Telephone and Date of birth in claim configuration which I can do it in SP (Service Provider) screen --> "Claim configuration" shown below.

Let's say I've user "John" configured in "User Profile" screen which give me option to enter FirstName, LastName, Organization, Email etc but it doesn't give me a option of PostalCode, DOB, Title, locality etc.

I wanted to populate all these values in UserStore (User Profile), so that all these values can go into the SAML Post. I am reading SAML Post assertions and I can get those values from Child Attributes or Attribute statements, so that I can check those value of User John against my local DB.

But I am not aware how we save values of "PostalCode", "DOB" or any custom Claim of my chioce in User Profile to make it available? Please help me. Please guide or Provide screen shots.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure new claim mapping and map your new claim uris in to a attribute of the user store. It seems to be that you have already created a claim mapping.  If you need to show new claims in the user profile UI, you need to tick on the `Supported by Default` check box in claim mapping configuration. 
More details about claim management of WSO2IS is available [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/05/02/claim-management-with-wso2-identity-server/)

Comment: We're unable to add custom claim LocatorId in the User Object of LDAP because we're not aware what attribute should be map to the LocatorId , but we can easily map it to the UserProfile its visible there, but when we're saving any value it gives error. Please help....Thanks, Neha

Comment: First,  you need to know the attributes which are supported by LDAP user object. Then you need to to map them correctly.  You can choose attribute from http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200001/msg00079.html and see..  You may need to try out and find the best one.